# How to compare words from .txt file against words in .xlsx file via Python? I will then extract these words by writing it to a new .xls file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I want to compare the common words from multiple `.txt` files based on the words in multiple `.xlsx` files. These are what the text files look like:

Text file 1:

```
(

apples),    kkkk, alloal

df, ja_tee

ffgg

hchh.hc

yuytu_member
```

Text file 2:

```
(

orange pplL

df

ffgg

hchhhc

yuytu_
```

Text file 3:

```
(

pear +lpdlpla;s

df

ffgg

hchhhc

yuytu_
```

I am trying to extract the words `apples`, `orange` and `pear`. These values are found in cell `A1` in my `.xlsx` file.

i.e. 
.xlsx file 1: cell A1 = apple

.xlsx file 2: cell A1 = orange

.xlsx file 3: cell A1 = pear

This is my code thus far:

```
import os, sys

import openpyxl

from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

import xlwt

from xlwt import Workbook

#The filepath that I will be saving my .xls file to:

filepath = ('C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxx/abc.xls')

#The .xls file:

wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\xxxx\\abc.xls', on_demand= True)

wb2 = Workbook()

sheet2 = wb2.add_sheet("xyz", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

#The .xlxs file that contains the words i want to compare w .txt file:
folder_path1 = os.chdir("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxxx/Test python dict")

for file in os.listdir(folder_path1):

  if file.endswith(".xlsx"):

    wb = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)

    ws = wb.active

    cell_range = ws['A1']

    dictionary = cell_range.value

    print(dictionary) #to check if the words/values are there

# Me writing the name of each .txt file to the .xls file:

for r, dir in enumerate(os.listdir("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxxx/txt test python")):
   sheet2.write(r+1,1,dir)

#Reading .txt file and trying to make the sentence into words instead of lines so that I can compare the .txt individual words with the .xlsx file:

import glob

path = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxxx/txt test python"

from os.path import isfile

files=filter(isfile,glob.glob('%s/*'%path))

for name in files:

  with open(name) as texts:

    data1 = texts.read().strip()

    import re

    data = re.split('[,.\n\s]',data1)

    for current_word in data:

      txtwords = current_word

      if txtwords in dictionary:

        print(txtwords)

        #sheet2.write(r+1,2,dir)

       # wb2.save(filepath)
```

However, I am unable to achieve the outcome that I want. The output I have now is:

`apples`

`orange`

`pear`

`pear`

why does it only print one common word?

Expected output:

`apple`

`orange`

`pear`

`apples`

`orange`

`pear`

Comment: sorry if my code seems messy, I'm still understanding how to use stackoverflow

Comment: you dont need ` in code

Comment: @Asif yep thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Hi all, i realised where my issue was. I needed to put it into a set in order for python to store all my values. Otherwise, it will just save the last text when th code runs. An example of my working code:
words= set()
for file in os.listdir(dict_folder):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        wb1 = load_workbook(join(dict_folder, file), data_only=True)
        ws = wb1.active
        cellvalues = ws["A1"].value
        #extract texts within brackets only:
        wordsextract = re.findall(r"\((.+?)\)", str(cellvalues))
        results = wordsextract[0]
        words.add(results)